# Autodesk Forge: In 3-legged "Authorize application" screen: Allow-button does not respond

Tags: c#, oauth, autodesk-forge

I wanted to create a 3-legged OAuth on (C#) desktop for Autodesk forge. I based my app on the article [3-legged OAuth on desktop apps (C# & WinForm)](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/10/3-legged-oauth-on-desktop-apps-c-winform.html). When I run my program, it lets me enter my username and then my password. But when it comes to "Authorize application", it does not react when I press the "Allow"-button. It turns dark blue when I hover over it but doesn't respond to any click.

I use ngrok to "capture" the Callback.

[image]

```
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public partial class oAuthForm : Form
    {
        private const string FORGE_CLIENT_ID = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        private const string FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = "zyxwvutsrqp";
        private const string FORGE_CALLBACK_URL = "https://bff25109c9dc.ngrok.io";
        private const string FORGE_BASE_URL = "https://developer.api.autodesk.com";
        private const string FORGE_SCOPE = "data:read data:write data:create data:search bucket:create bucket:read bucket:update bucket:delete"; // assuming a full scope

        private WebBrowser2 wb = new WebBrowser2();

        public oAuthForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            wb.NavigateError += new WebBrowserNavigateErrorEventHandler(wb_NavigateError);
            Controls.Add(wb);

            // this is a basic code sample, quick & dirty way to get the Authentication string
            string authorizeUrl = FORGE_BASE_URL + string.Format("/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}", FORGE_CLIENT_ID, FORGE_CALLBACK_URL, WebUtility.UrlEncode(FORGE_SCOPE));

            // now let's open the Authorize page.
            wb.Navigate(authorizeUrl);
        }

        private void wb_NavigateError(object sender, WebBrowserNavigateErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // This will track errors: we want to track the 404 when the login
            // page redirects to our callback URL, let's check if is the error
            // we're tracking.
            Uri callbackURL = new Uri(e.Url);
            if (e.Url.IndexOf(FORGE_CALLBACK_URL) == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, the authorization failed", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            // extract the code
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(callbackURL.Query);
            string code = query["code"];

            // now we have the code, let's make a Http call to 
            // /authentication/v1/gettoken 
            // and get the access_token...

            // you can use RestSharp for it, but I'll stop the sample here

            // you may want to close this form..
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

The Visual Studio solution can be found [here](https://bertildegroot0279@dev.azure.com/bertildegroot0279/Forge_3legged/_git/Forge_3legged).

Comment: Is there a way to capture any console logs from the webview component in the C# app? If the "Allow" button doesn't react, I'm thinking there might be some errors that prevent the page from proceeding.

Comment: I looked for a way to capture logs but couldn't find how to do it. I found a solution in using CefSharp as a webbrowser. It has a LoadError-event that triggers when I press the allow button. That way I can capture the response and close the form / webbrowser by code.